# Is there a way to query Firestore for a field that is either null or is an array that contains a certain value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my case, I'd like to retrieve all of the documents in a collection that have the field `users` as either null or an array containing a specific user id, like `userId123`.

I know I can achieve one or the other by themselves with a query like this:

```js
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('documents')
  .where('users', isEqualTo: null);
```

or

```js
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('documents')
  .where('users', arrayContains: 'userId123');
```

But when I try to combine them like this, it doesn't work:

```js
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('documents')
  .where('users', arrayContains: 'userId123')
  .where('users', isEqualTo: null);
```

I know I can perform these queries separately and just combine them client side, but it seems like this should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple `where` clauses in a query, they are `AND`'ed together, so the behavior you get with two `where` calls is expected.

I'm trying to think of a way you can implement the query you want, but somehow nothing comes to mind. If I think of something, I'll update - but of course I hope someone else may think of an alternate approach too.

Comment: Yes, now that I'm reading the documentation, it's stated:
"Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical OR queries. The in, and array-contains-any operators support a logical OR of up to 10 equality (==) or array-contains conditions on a single field. For other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app."
From https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations.
So I guess I'll just merge the queries in my app. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As [@Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) pointed out, concatenated `where`s are `AND`'ed together, so you will need to merge them separately afterwards. This has been covered in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d), by Renaud Tarnec.

Currently, I'm doing this:

1. Create both promise requests.
2. Use `Promise.all` to fetch them concurrently.
3. Use local JS/TS to concatenate the resulting docs in a list.

I wish Firestore provided a way to make a logical `OR` out of the box, since it's such a common type of request, but so far they apparently don't.